# Which is the proper way to end the execution of the application inside a constructor block?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, exit, terminate

I've noticed that if I try to use the `Application.Exit` instruction inside a constructor sub it does not take any effect, so what should be the proper way to end the execution of the application in this circunstances?

I know that I could just use the application events to cancel the `startup` event, or wait for the `Load` or `Shown` event to properly exit the application calling the `Application.Exit` method, but I'm asking this for learn the proper way to do it in a constructor sub without using the `End` statement, in case that could be possibly.

This is an example:

```
Public Class Form1: Inherits Form

''' <summary>
''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Form1"/> class.
''' </summary>
Public Sub New()

     Application.Exit
     ' End

End Class
```

Comment: I think not, it throws an 'System.ObjectDisposedException' exception, the same for Dispose. thanks for comment!

Comment: my bad I tested on WPF not WinForms

Comment: How about `Load += (s, e) => Close();` or whatever the VB equivalent is, You just need to make sue `Application.Run` finished loading first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment.Exit(0) will do the trick.

Comment: But is not a question about find a tricky way, the documentation for that method says that it will terminate the process inmediatelly, I suppose that means in the same way as `End` statement, while on the other hand the `Application.Exit` method informs that the application must terminate, but waits for the necessary messages to be processes and then terminate it, so, if I'm not wrong, `Environment.Exit` should be so injurious as `End`, but I'm not totaly sure of this.

Comment: The difference is that `Application.Exit` can only be called/used after the `Application.Run` has been called.  The reason why when you called `Application.Exit` and it didnt work is because the order of events when you run the application (assuming its just a winforms app) it instantiates the form first before calling `Application.Run`.  If you have the `Application.Exit` code in your constructor then the `Application.Run` hasn't been called yet.  However, when calling `Environment.Exit` it terminates the process and gives the operating system the exit code so you dont need to call Run first.